# How can i group by in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

The Tags class is

```
public class Tags
    {
        public int TagId;
        public string Tag;
        public string TagLink;
        public int TagCount;
    }
```

and my query is

```
 var v = db.QuestionTags
           .GroupBy(n => n.Tag.Tag1)
           .Select(n => new Tags
           {
               Tag = n.Key,
               TagCount = n.Count()
           }
           )
           .OrderByDescending(n => n.TagCount);
```

The problem with the approach above is that i cannot map also the `TagId` and the `TagLink`. How can i fix that?

Comment: Why don't you group by those properties also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that for each `Tag` you get a unique `TagId` and `TagLink`, you can use `First()` to set them:

```
var v = db.QuestionTags
    .GroupBy(n => n.Tag.Tag1)
    .Select(n => new Tags {
        Tag = n.Key,
        TagCount = n.Count(),
        TagId = n.First().TagId,
        TagLink = n.First().TagLink
    })
    .OrderByDescending(n => n.TagCount);
```

If these properties may be different for the same `Tag`, group by their combination:

```
var v = db.QuestionTags
    .GroupBy(n => new {n.Tag.Tag1, n.TagId, n.TagLink})
    .Select(n => new Tags {
        Tag = n.Key.Tag1,
        TagCount = n.Count(),
        TagId = n.Key.TagId,
        TagLink = n.Key.TagLink
    })
    .OrderByDescending(n => n.TagCount);
```